# Why isnt my update from client working?

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query, insert-update

This is a frustrating roadblock. I need to update and increment values an array inside of a collection. To achieve this, I'm accessing the collection using the MongoDB syntax like so:

```
var selectedBargain = Session.get('selectedBargain');

//Confirm that Session.get is successful
console.log("SelectedID is: "+selectedBargain);

buyList.update(selectedBargain, {$inc: {nrOfUnreadMessages: 1} });
buyList.update(selectedBargain, {$set: {messageToggle: 0} });
```

The console successfully prints out:  **SelectedID is: nEXHQFEt6kZ9Wzvg3**

Strangely the update query works successfully When I run it via the console as:

```
buyList.update("nEXHQFEt6kZ9Wzvg3", {$inc: {nrOfUnreadMessages: 1} })
```

I have tried changing my code to:

```
buyList.update({_id: selectedBargain}, {$inc: {nrOfUnreadMessages: 1} });
buyList.update({_id: selectedBargain}, {$set: {messageToggle: 0} });
```

... to No avail.

Can someone tell me why it doesnt work in my code? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You must have already checked. but asking anyway. are you sure you're connecting to same DB while running in both code and console?

Comment: @KaSh Well I only have one buyList. And I am and to update only via console.

Comment: When you say it works successfully when you run it in the console, I assume to mean in Chrome/Firefox?  Does the `$set` work, and only the `$inc` fails, or do they both fail?  What do you see in the WS section in Dev Tools/Network on Chrome when you run the code vs. when you run via JS console?  You should see the DDP updates go over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CodeChimp, @Kash I am terribly sorry guys. I figured it out. 
It seems like I never traced the sequence of the code to the very end. Further on (outside the scope of what I posted here) was another function with the query:

```
buyList.update(ChatSubMessagesId, {$set: {nrOfUnreadMessages: 0} })
buyList.update(ChatSubMessagesId, {$set: {messageToggle:1} } )
```

The result was that it would reverse the desired code being:

```
buyList.update({_id: selectedBargain}, {$inc: {nrOfUnreadMessages: 1} });
buyList.update({_id: selectedBargain}, {$set: {messageToggle: 0} });
```

Its taken me so many hours to realize. So embarrassing!